# OpenIddict grant_type password is invalid client

Tags: c#, .net-7.0, openiddict

I'm using OpenIddict with password flow or password grant type. following the sample here https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples for `Hollastin`

I tried to make request the token with form encoded with these parameters:

- username=testuser
- password=mypassword
- grant_type=password

after sent post request and I got `401 Unauthorized` with this message:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_client",
  "error_description": "The specified 'client_id' is invalid.",
  "error_uri": "https://documentation.openiddict.com/errors/ID2052"
}
```

Here is my server configured.

```
.AddServer(options =>
{
    options.SetTokenEndpointUris("/connect/token");

    options.RegisterScopes(Scopes.Email, Scopes.Profile, Scopes.Roles);

    options.AllowPasswordFlow();

    options.AcceptAnonymousClients();

    options.AddDevelopmentEncryptionCertificate()
           .AddDevelopmentSigningCertificate();

    options.UseAspNetCore()
           .EnableTokenEndpointPassthrough();
})
```

I still find out the solution for this. Do any have a suggestion for this?
ENV:

- .NET7
- OpenIddict 4.1

Answer (score 2):

Some suggestions can be given to you:

1. add `client_id` & `client_secret` in your request.
2. add `Permissions.GrantTypes.Password,` to this client permissions.